# Problem with for looping [troublehsooting]

Tags: r, loops, plot

I am tring to reduce some repetitive lines of code into a loop, but I am not succeeding.

The code is:

```
  points(5, obsq[1,2], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
  points(5, obsq[1,3], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
  points(5, obsq[1,4], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
  
  points(15, obsq[2,2], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
  points(15, obsq[2,3], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
  points(15, obsq[2,4], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
  
  points(25, obsq[3,2], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
  points(25, obsq[3,3], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
  points(25, obsq[3,4], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
  
  points(45, obsq[4,2], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
  points(45, obsq[4,3], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
  points(45, obsq[4,4], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
```

And I have tried to do a for loop to plot these points into an existing plot:

```
defB <- c(5,15,25,45)
defX <- c(1:4)
defY <- c(2:4)
   
  for(i in length(defB)){
    for(j in length(defX)){
      for(k in length(defY)){
        points(defB[i], obsq[defX[j],defY[k]], pch=21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
        
      }
    }
  }
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: go from 1 to N with `1:length(XXX)` in your loop

Comment: Thanks, what a silly mistake! I also realised I had an additional for loop that wasn't necessary

Comment: For defensive programming, use `seq_len(length(XXX))` instead of `1:length(XXX)`. The problem only arises if you (accidentally?) have a zero-length vector: the intuitive response would be that `1:length(XXX)` would return nothing, but it reduces to `1:0` which returns `c(1, 0)` (length 2) instead. `seq_len` will not do that.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to attack this without loops:

```r
defB <- c(5,15,25,45)
defX <- c(1:4)
defY <- c(2:4)
eg <- expand.grid(X=defX, Y=defY)
eg$B <- rep(defB, each = length(defY))
eg
#    X Y  B
# 1  1 2  5
# 2  2 2  5
# 3  3 2  5
# 4  4 2 15
# 5  1 3 15
# 6  2 3 15
# 7  3 3 25
# 8  4 3 25
# 9  1 4 25
# 10 2 4 45
# 11 3 4 45
# 12 4 4 45
```

From here, sending this to points is as easy as

```r
points(eg$B, obsq[cbind(eg$X,eg$Y)], pch = 21, col = "brown1", bg = "brown1")
```